# After Insert trigger behaviour if insertion execution fails

Tags: apex, trigger, community, case, after-trigger

I have a custom object named 'shift_cancellation__c'. This custom object records are being populated by parsing an email. I have a class named 'shiftCancellationListener' that parses the emails and populate the 'shift_cancellation__c' object. Then, I have set up an after insert apex Trigger(named 'createShiftCancellationCases') on this custom object. Also after a case is created I have again set up an after insert apex trigger(named checkViolation) on the case object. My question is:
1) if checkViolation trigger has a SOQL query that returns zero rows then will this obstruct in the creation of shift_cancellation__c records?

Backstory
Whenever an email is sent to the salesforce service address a shift_cancellation record is created. This then triggers a case. After a case is created this should trigger checkviolation trigger. But in my case a soql query is returning zero rows and creating an error. This results in no creation of shift_cancellation record showing "CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CreateShiftCancellationCases: execution of AfterInsert" error.[image]

Comment: Can you post your code also?

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger is expecting exactly one row:

```
some_object record = [select ... from ... where ... ];
```

But there's no results returned. Your trigger should not assume that there's exactly one row being returned. Three standard designs for this are as follows.

## Assign to List, use First Record

```
some_object[] records = [select ... from ... where ...];
if(records.isEmpty()) {
  return; // Nothing to do
}
some_object record = records[0];
// keep going with the rest of the logic
```

## For Loop

```
some_object record;
for(some_object queryRecord: [select ... from ... where ...]) {
  record = queryRecord;
}
if(record == null) {
  return; // nothing to do
}
// keep going
```

## try-catch

```
try {
  some_object record = [select ... from ... where ...];
  // keep going
} catch(QueryException e) {
  // no rows were selected
}
```

Even if you absolutely expect a record to be returned, your code must not assume that such a record will be returned, and should be able to gracefully handle this situation.

In any case, your trigger's logic is faulty. It is perfectly possible for a query to return zero rows without causing the trigger to halt with a fatal error. It's up to the developer to make sure this happens, if appropriate.

There may be times when you want to present an error if no rows are found, so no matter which technique you use, you should use addError on the records in Trigger.new (or Trigger.old for deleted records) to gracefully block the DML operation.